# AWS Amplify SPA React + Cognito (Microsoft Azure Ad Enterprise SSO Enabled ) + Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using React for developing a single page application and AWS Amplify for serverless integration. To Sign-in the user, I have successfully configured the AWS Cognito console with SAML so that our organization users can log in the application without register and can access the AWS resources. We are using Microsoft Azure Ad as the Identity Provider.

Now inside the application, I have to implement a search that can query the Azure AD users using the Microsoft Graph API.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'J')
```

We have the appropriate permission for accessing the graph. 
We have the client ID, secret ID & we have enabled implicit grant flow for the App in Azure.

Since I'm using AWS Amplify and Cognito to authenticate the user, I receive IdToken and accessToken when the user login into the application.

```
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
const idToken = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
const accessToken = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken;
```

But this id-token and access-token is of Cognito and not of Microsoft Azure AD.

Microsoft provides [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) (for OAuth 2 implicit grant flow) for making graph API calls on SPA but we cannot use that in our application since we are using AWS Amplify (Cognito) for authentication.

So How to make graph calls with the help of AWS Lamda or any other AWS services. It would be really helpful if you recommend any other approach.

Comment: If you authenticate against Cognito, you can't use Graph API from your front-end. Your back-end could do the call with Client credentials flow and application permissions (not delegated permissions).

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest how to implement the same with AWS Amplify (Rest API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID token and access token from Cognito don't have access to Microsoft Graph data.

To call Microsoft Graph, your app must acquire an access token from the Microsoft identity platform. The access token contains information about the permissions it has for the resources and APIs available through Microsoft Graph. See [auth-concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts).

As juunas suggested, you could implement the Client credentials flow to access Graph resources.

Comment: Thanks **[OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)** - If we go with this approach we have to make server-side calls I don't understand how to approach this using AWS Amplify ( Using REST API ) or AWS Lambda function or any other AWS method. (making the [admin consent call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#recommended-sign-the-user-into-your-app), responds with redirects to the redirect URL, how to take care of that)

Comment: 0


I am trying to find a test project in ReactJS runs and SSO's an user with Azure AD that links to AWS Cognito.

For example, how do I get users to show something like a Hosted UI that they sign in to Azure AD and then Redirect them back to ReactJS to extract the token.

Its very hard to find a test project, as I did see Amazon Amplify, but nothing specific.

Does anyone have any test projects to share please..